# ArangoDB - Collection not found error though the collection is created

Tags: python, arangodb, pyarango

I am creating an edge "has_taken" between two documents as follows:

`sin_graph.createEdge("has_taken", userDoc._id, tripDoc._id, edgeAttributes={})`

And I am getting the following error:

`File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/pyArango/graph.py", line 135, in createEdge
raise CreationError("Unable to create edge, %s" % r.json()["errorMessage"], data)
CreationError: Unable to create edge, collection not found. Errors: {u'code': 404, u'errorNum': 1203, u'errorMessage': u'collection not found', u'error': True}`

The collection with the name "has_taken" is present and yet I am getting the above error.

Comment: Can you write more details? where to you get `sin_graph` from?

Comment: I got my graph by the following command

sin_graph = db.graphs['Graph_name']

I have created this graph using the GUI of arangoDB

Comment: Are you sure you are using the correct db? and not _system>

Comment: Yes I was using the correct DB. I think I got the mistake, I have read that a graph can contain similar type of edges. In my graph I was entering an edge with a different to, from config.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it may be because you made a collection of type Collection and not of type Edge (haha, confusing, I know.)

But when making the collection called "has_taken", instead of

```
db.createCollection(className="Collection", name="has_taken")
```

try

```
db.createCollection(className="Edges", name="has_taken")
```

I noticed that when I was reading [this](http://bioinfo.iric.ca/~daoudat/pyArango/database.html#pyArango.database.Database.createCollection) page. (Look at the very top of your screen when you click that link. The function and its description is right up there and it mentions this difference.)

> ```
> createCollection(className='Collection', waitForSync=False, **colArgs)[source]
> ```
>
> Creates a collection and returns it. ClassName the name of a class inheriting from Collection or Egdes, it can also be set to ‘Collection’ or ‘Edges’ in order to create untyped collections of documents or edges.

Answer (score 0):

I have transpiled the [social graph example](https://docs.arangodb.com/latest/Manual/Graphs/#the-social-graph) example to pyArango; It ilustrates the sequence of things to do when maintaining graph data with it:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
from pyArango.connection import *
from pyArango.graph import *
from pyArango.collection import *


class Social(object):
        class male(Collection) :
            _fields = {
                "name" : Field()
            }

        class female(Collection) :
            _fields = {
                "name" : Field()
            }

        class relation(Edges) :
            _fields = {
                "number" : Field()
            }

        class social(Graph) :

            _edgeDefinitions = (EdgeDefinition ('relation',
                                                fromCollections = ["female", "male"],
                                                toCollections = ["female", "male"]),)
            _orphanedCollections = []


        def __init__(self):
               self.conn = Connection(username="root", password="")

               self.db = self.conn["_system"]
               if self.db.hasGraph('social'):
                   raise Exception("The social graph was already provisioned! remove it first")

               self.female   = self.db.createCollection("female")
               self.male     = self.db.createCollection("male")

               self.relation = self.db.createCollection("relation")

               g = self.db.createGraph("social")

               a = g.createVertex('female', {"name": 'Alice',  "_key": 'alice'});
               b = g.createVertex('male',  {"name": 'Bob',    "_key": 'bob'});
               c = g.createVertex('male',   {"name": 'Charly', "_key": 'charly'});
               d = g.createVertex('female', {"name": 'Diana',  "_key": 'diana'});
               a.save()
               b.save()
               c.save()
               d.save()

               g.link('relation', a, b, {"type": 'married', "_key": 'aliceAndBob'})
               g.link('relation', a, c, {"type": 'friend', "_key": 'aliceAndCharly'})
               g.link('relation', c, d, {"type": 'married', "_key": 'charlyAndDiana'})
               g.link('relation', b, d, {"type": 'friend', "_key": 'bobAndDiana'})


Social()
```